# Automatically logged out of all Google services periodically

Tags: google-play

I'm getting logged out of all Google services a set period after opening the browser or logging in, it's about 20 minutes, maybe less. Occasionally the log in page will automatically redirect to a "clear cache and cookies" help page, however following the instructions on this page changes nothing and a short time later it logs me out again. This is particularly annoying when writing a response to a review on the Google Play Developer Console, because as soon as it detects being logged out it greys the text box so that it's not possible to copy and paste the message and it is not saved as a draft, it has to be written again. It's important to note this happens regardless of the browser being used and regardless of whether or not you are logged in on multiple devices. This is something Google really need to fix. Has anyone else suffered these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I've found a solution, as an Android app developer I always have a bunch of tabs open such as Google Play Developer Console for reviews and statistics and Google Wallet for financial reports. It turns out the problem is related to Google Wallet because if I close this tab, it won't log me out of all Google services. It appears this is a bug with the Google Wallet service. So to clarify this is a bug with Google Wallet, so if you're experiencing this problem like me, always close this tab after viewing the reports (the one launched from the Play console under financial reports).